# Mitmproxy load and unload scripts with python

Tags: python, concurrency, proxy, mitmproxy, libmproxy

I'm a running a proxy as suggested in Mitmproxy github [examples](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/flowbasic):

```
from libmproxy import proxy, flow

class MitmProxy(flow.FlowMaster):
    def run(self):
        try:
            flow.FlowMaster.run(self)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.shutdown()

  
    def handle_request(self, r):
        f = flow.FlowMaster.handle_request(self, r)

        if f:
            r.reply()
        return f

    def handle_response(self, r):
        f = flow.FlowMaster.handle_response(self, r)
 
        if f:
            r.reply()
        return f



config = proxy.ProxyConfig(
    cacert = os.path.expanduser("~/.ssl/mitmproxy.pem")
)
state = flow.State()
server = proxy.ProxyServer(config, 8083)
m = MitmProxy(server, state)
try:
    m.run()
except Exception, e:
    print e.message
    m.shutdown()
```

I want to handle each request/response without blocking the others,
for that i need to use the concurrent decorator and scripts

my question is: how do i load and unload scripts to the proxy running in this configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use concurrent mode with script loading.
Here is an [example](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/nonblocking.py) for this kind of usage

I preferred to implement the mitmproxy logic in the flow level.
You can use this code

```
def handle_response(self, r):
    reply = f.response.reply
        f.response.reply = controller.DummyReply()
        if hasattr(reply, "q"):
            f.response.reply.q = reply.q
        def run(): 
            pass
        threading.Thread(target=run)
```

Comment: tnx, that helped me alot. i also tried to load scripts from the code by doing. m.load_script(path to script) but it gave me some error. after further digging i found that someone reported it as a bug, and the dev fixed it, here is the link to issue: [https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/267](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/267)

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to copy how handle_concurrent_reply works in [libmproxy.script](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/42d4a2fae96b8b4ba35d3a88e20f278d79a0ccc6/libmproxy/script.py)

```
f = flow.FlowMaster.handle_request(self,r)
if f:
        def run():
           request.reply() #if you forget this you'll end up in a loop and never reply
threading.Thread(target=run).start()  #this will start run
```